# How to copy data from one dataframe to another dataframe(empty dataframe with defined columns names) without copying the header

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, copy, concatenation

I have a requirement to convert xml to csv. However, the problem comes when the xml come with different order of tags / missing tags. I want to retain the ordering of columns/ structure of dataframe.

Comment: Can you share some data examples to make the question clearer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try using [.copy() to copy the columns to the other columns](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/78119/pandas-copy-different-columns-from-different-dataframes-to-a-new-dataframe) - Sai Sreenivas.